# PostgreSQL - Move data from jsonb array to separate table

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

In my PostgreSQL database I have the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE slides (
    id integer,
    question jsonb DEFAULT '{}'::jsonb
);

CREATE TABLE suggestions (
    id integer,
    slide_id integer,
    suggestion_text text
);


INSERT INTO slides (id, question)
  VALUES (1, '{"suggestions": ["Suggestion 1", "Suggestion 2"]}');
```

Now I want to move `question->>'suggestions'` to a `suggestions` table. So

`SELECT * FROM suggestions;` should return:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
id     | suggestion_test   | slide_id
------------------------------------------------------------------
1      | Suggestion 1      | 1     
2      | Suggestion 2      | 1
```

How can I do this in PostgreSQL? Here is DBfiddle that You can experiment with:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oEQf7ntttV5Wu9wyiXbEFk/0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the column `suggestions.id` should be `serial`:

```
CREATE TABLE suggestions (
    id serial,
    slide_id integer,
    suggestion_text text
);
```

Use the function [`jsonb_array_elements_text()`.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html)

```
insert into suggestions(slide_id, suggestion_text)
select 
    id as slide_id, 
    value as suggestion_text
from slides
cross join jsonb_array_elements_text(question->'suggestions');
```

[DbFiddle.](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oEQf7ntttV5Wu9wyiXbEFk/1)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `jsonb_array_elements()`:

```
select jsonb_array_elements(question->'suggestions')
from slides;
```